# How to set max request body size in traefik ingress controller for kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

It's very easy to set up **max request body size** with nginx using [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) directive. How can I do the same with kubernetes  [traefik ingress controller](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/kubernetes-ingress/). I know there is [maxrequestbodybytes](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/buffering/#maxrequestbodybytes) directive to do so but, I'm lost with how to set it up in **yaml** file describing my ingress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't so easy to figure this out. There is a funky [multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/) way of specifying this config in **yaml** file. Please check option **traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/buffering** to see he pipe (`|`) oprator in acction.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
    domain: example.com
    deployment: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/buffering: |
      maxrequestbodybytes: 31457280
      memrequestbodybytes: 62914560
spec:
  etc....
```

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to work? According to the official documentation this should be configured at `Service` object level and not `Ingress` level, see: https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/3972

Comment: Yes, I am sure it works! If you don't belief test it.

Comment: I've just tested it, and it doesn't work for me. However, setting the annotation at `Service` object level works well (I use traefik 1.7).